# PHP class and javascript

Tags: php, oop

i am working on PHP login form. I must use a class:

```
  <?php
    class loginController_ extends Controller_
    {
        public $loginok;
    // Session
    session_start();


    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die();
    mysql_select_db("db") or die();

    // pobranie danych:
    $user = $_POST['us'];
    $pawss = $_POST['pwd'];     

    $login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user ='$user'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($login);

    $dbpass = $row['pass'];
    $dbuser = $row['user'];

    if ($pass==$dbpass && $user==$dbuser)
    {
        $loginok = TRUE;


        $_SESSION['user']=$user;
        }
    else
    {   
        $loginok = FALSE;

    }

    }

    if ($loginok==TRUE)
    {
    echo 'yes';
    }

    else 
    {
    echo 'no';
    }
    ?>
```

I have declared variable "loginok" as public, because, I'd like to return value of this php file (echo 'yes';/ echo 'no') to my script, which checks being of user. Unfortunatelly id does not work. How to hand over value of "loginok" out of the class?

Comment: How exactly is this related to JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: How you're getting it at the moment? do you create an object and access this property? (or method and what it returns)

Comment: please read a bit more about oop in php and you'll get you're answer realy fast .

Comment: Please have a look at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php before you attempt to use classes. Building some functionality using procedural programming and just putting it in a `class loginController` isn't enough.

Comment: What does this have to do with Javascript?

Comment: Voted to close. The OP has no idea what a class is, and should read a book on PHP .. or at the very least, some documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The view that calls this controller needs to access that variable and then pass it to the JS.

There's no way your code would work right now as all that code needs to go inside a method in the loginController_ class. Call that method, and have it **return** the result.

Once you have that result, you need to give it to the view. If you mix PHP and HTML you can simply do this

```
<script>
   var loginStatus = "<?php echo $loginStatus ?>"
</script>
```

If you're using a framework, you can usually do something like `$this->view->loginStatus = $loginStatus;`. Can't give you a concrete answer until you tell us what framework you're using. In any case, your PHP class is broke.